# Application/zip GET function call

Tags: r

I have made a GET call with this link "https://data.bus-data.dft.gov.uk/timetable/download/gtfs-file/wales/" and the content type is application/zip. I would like to unzip it but I can't find out how. Right now it is in my environment under data as a large response, but I cannot figure out how to unzip and access the data.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `download.file` to donwload the zip:

```
download.file("https://data.bus-data.dft.gov.uk/timetable/download/gtfs-file/wales/", "itm_wales_gtfs.zip", method = "curl")

unzip("itm_wales_gtfs.zip", exdir = "itm_wales_gtfs")
```

Comment: Thank you! that works, although I am not sure about how to save the files into a directory...

Comment: You could add the directory name to the filename of the destfile, i.e. `destfile = "PATH/itm_wales_gtfs.zip"`.